# katalon / groovy if element not present with else statement

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I need help in katalon studio groovy script for if else statement. If the element 'Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity' is not found then it should skip the current iteration and continue with the next iteration. 12th line in the code I have tried the if statement but it is not working.

```
for (def row = 1; row <= findTestData('Ship Plan Data').getRowNumbers(); row++) 
    {
                 WebUI.delay(2)
                 WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_Scan or type SKU_itemId'), 
                 findTestData('Ship Plan Data').getValue('fnsku', row))

                 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                 WebUI.delay(1)
                 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                 WebUI.delay(2)

        if (WebUI.verifyElementNotPresent(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity',10,FailureHandling.OPTIONAL) )==true)
                        {continue} 
        else{
             WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity'), findTestData('Ship Plan Data').getValue('Quantity',
                                row))
              rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)     
              WebUI.delay(2)
              rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
              WebUI.delay(3)

              WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_(You can select bin from'), findTestData('Ship Plan Data').getValue(
                                'bin', row))

              rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
              WebUI.delay(2)
              rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
              WebUI.delay(2)

              WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/button_RECEIVE  STORE'))
             }
    }
```

Comment: *verifyElementNotpresent* looks like the P should be capitalized?  No idea about the rest.  Can you put a println in next to "continue" to see if you're matching?

Comment: Thanks,did capitalize. the error it throws 
Test Cases/shipplancase2 FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1536501262795.findTestObject() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling) values: [Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity, 10, OPTIONAL]

Comment: Did you link your data file with Katalon (File > New > New Test Data)?

Comment: yes, it picks up the values from the file and continues iteration till the object is found. once the object is not found it gives a error

Answer (score 0):

findTestObject() accepts strings as argument, so the integer and the failure handling need to go.

Comment: if (WebUI.verifyElementNotPresent(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity') )== true) hope you said this tried no luck

Comment: You can keep the timeout and the failure handling, but inside of the verifyElementNotPresent(), not findTestObject().

Comment: You said 'no luck'. But, are you getting the same error message?

Comment: Tried this
`if (WebUI.verifyElementNotPresent(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity'),10,FailureHandling.OPTIONAL ) ==true ) { continue
   } 
 else{ `

got this error

Test Cases/shipplancase2 FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to set text '450' of object 'Object Repository/Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Comment: The element might be present but not visible or clickable. Try using `WebUI.verifyElementClickable()` or `WebUI.verifyElementVisible()`.

Comment: `for (def row = 1; row <= findTestData('Ship Plan Data').getRowNumbers(); row++) {
.
.
if (WebUI.verifyElementNotVisible(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/div_Please update the dimensio'), 5)== true) { steps....  }
 else {continue}
}`

else continue should go to for statement and go ahead with next loop

it gives a error Test Cases/sample FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.verifyElementNotVisible() is applicable for argument types:

Comment: According to documentation, [verifyElementNotVisible()](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Verify+Element+Not+Visible) doesn't have a timeout value. But I'm not sure this is true. Try with notVisibleInViewport.

Answer (score 0):

you have typo in if command:

```
if (WebUI.verifyElementNotPresent(findTestObject('Page_Quick Inbound/input_Bad_quantity'),10,FailureHandling.OPTIONAL) == true)
```

finTestObject(),10,FailureHandling